# How to re-enable a click event?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling

I want to disable the onclick event on a rectangle when I click on it but how to enable it again on a second click?

I thought I would need to use the onclick attribute of the rectangle but that has a value of null every time.

```js
const svgViewport = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 150);

let myData = [
  [{
      x: 30,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 30,
      y: 60
    }
  ],
  [{
      x: 60,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 60,
      y: 60
    }
  ],
  [{
      x: 90,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 90,
      y: 60
    }

  ],
  [{
      x: 120,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 120,
      y: 60
    }
  ]
];

let buttons = [{
    x: 40,
    y: 100
  },
  {
    x: 70,
    y: 100
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 100
  }
];


const groups = svgViewport.selectAll(null)
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

const circles = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(d => d)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => d.x)
  .attr("cy", (d) => d.y)
  .attr("r", 10);

const button = svgViewport.selectAll("g")
  .data(buttons)
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d) => d.x)
  .attr("y", (d) => d.y)
  .attr("class", "btn")
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "a" + i)
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .on("click", (d, i) => {
    let el = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[i].id;
    console.log("you clicked on button with id=" + el);
    svgViewport.selectAll("#" + el).on("click", null);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I want to enable/disable my rectangles using d3.js, as far as I know buttons can't be appended to the svg

Comment: *"I want to disable the onclick event on a rectangle when I click on it but how to enable it again on a second click"*... I'm not following this: you click the rectangle, the event function works and then the listener is disabled. Then, when you click it again, the listener is re-enabled, and the event function works... Therefore, it's **always** working! Please explain it better.

Comment: It works for the first two clicks for example the rectangle with id a0 when I click it this will run  console.log("you clicked on button with id="+el) for the second click this will run var kl= svgViewport.selectAll("#"+el).on("click",null) and for the 3rd,4th click this will run again  varkl=svgViewport.selectAll("#"+el).on("click",null) but I want to run this code again for the 3rd click :  console.log("you clicked on button with id="+el) so I want a different functionality for every even and odd clicks

Answer (score 1):

At first your question was quite unclear, but I believe you explained what you want in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505775/how-to-reenable-click-event#comment101486757_57505775):

> I want a different functionality for every even and odd clicks

That being the case, you don't need to attach/detach the event handler (which makes your question a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Instead of that, let's create a **counter** and run different functions according the counter being odd or even.

For that, we'll create a [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

First, call the listener function immediately in the callback:

```
button.on("click", clickButtons());
```

This is important for creating the closure because, unlike just referencing the function...

```
button.on("click", clickButtons);
```

..., which is the most common approach, by calling the listener function and getting its return value we'll return *another* function (see below).

Now comes the listener function:

```
function clickButtons() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function(d, i, n) {
    if (++counter % 2) {
      console.log("You clicked on a button with id " + n[i].id)
    } else {
      console.log("click skipped!")
    }
  }
}
```

This is what it does:

First, it declares a `counter`, set to `0`. This `counter` is accessible in the inner function, which is actually returned. Therefore, the three arguments passed by `selection.on` are captured by that inner function:

```
return function(d, i, n) {
//arguments-----^--^--^
```

These arguments, the datum, the index and the group, are fundamental for doing whatever you do in the functions.

Then comes the important part: at every click, you increase the `counter` and test it remainder dividing it by two, which returns only two values, `1`(truthy) and `0` (falsy):

```
if (++counter % 2) {
    //do stuff here for odd counter
} else {
   //do stuff here for even counter
};
```

And here is the demo: the ID of the element is displayed only every other time you click the red buttons:

```js
const svgViewport = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 150);

let myData = [
  [{
      x: 30,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 30,
      y: 60
    }
  ],
  [{
      x: 60,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 60,
      y: 60
    }
  ],
  [{
      x: 90,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 90,
      y: 60
    }

  ],
  [{
      x: 120,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 120,
      y: 60
    }
  ]
];

let buttons = [{
    x: 40,
    y: 100
  },
  {
    x: 70,
    y: 100
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 100
  }
];


const groups = svgViewport.selectAll(null)
  .data(myData)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

const circles = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(d => d)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => d.x)
  .attr("cy", (d) => d.y)
  .attr("r", 10);

const button = svgViewport.selectAll("g")
  .data(buttons)
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d) => d.x)
  .attr("y", (d) => d.y)
  .attr("class", "btn")
  .attr("id", (d, i) => "a" + i)
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .on("click", clickButtons());

function clickButtons() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function(d, i, n) {
    if (++counter % 2) {
      console.log("You clicked on a button with id " + n[i].id)
    } else {
      console.log("click skipped!")
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 30% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```